# JQuery refactoring code assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am learning to code and I have some code that is repeated 3 times in 3 different files.

How can I refactor the following code, so that the code is called from a common source passing in the id of the element that is different for the three files.

I have tried many ways but I continually get errors. The following code is the same in all three files except for the input id: 'id_new_password1` which is different for each

How can I refactor the following code so that I can pass in the element id and have the same body of code:

This is the 1st section of code:

```
$("input#id_new_password1").on("focus keyup", function () {
    var a = $(this).val();
    $("#password_change_recommendation_wrap").fadeIn(400);
    // minimum of 12 characters in password length.
    if (a.length >= 12) {
        $("#password_length").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
    } else {
        $("#password_length").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
    }

    // minimum of 1 digit in password.
    if (a.match(/\d/)) {
        $("#password_digit").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
    } else {
        $("#password_digit").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
    }

    // minimum of 1 uppercase character in password.
    if (a.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        $("#password_upper_case").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
    } else {
        $("#password_upper_case").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
    }

    // minimum of 1 lowercase character in password.
    if (a.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        $("#password_lower_case").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
    } else {
        $("#password_lower_case").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
    }

    // minimum of 1 special character in password.
    if ( a.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) {
        $("#password_special_character").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
    } else {
        $("#password_special_character").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
    }
});
```

This is the 2nd section of code:

```
    $("input#id_password1").on("focus keyup", function () {
        var a = $(this).val();
        $("#password_registration_recommendation_wrap").fadeIn(400);
        // minimum of 12 characters in password length.
        if (a.length >= 12) {
            $("#password_length").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
        } else {
            $("#password_length").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
        }

        // minimum of 1 digit in password.
        if (a.match(/\d/)) {
            $("#password_digit").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
        } else {
            $("#password_digit").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
        }

        // minimum of 1 uppercase character in password.
        if (a.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            $("#password_upper_case").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
        } else {
            $("#password_upper_case").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
        }

        // minimum of 1 lowercase character in password.
        if (a.match(/[a-z]/)) {
            $("#password_lower_case").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
        } else {
            $("#password_lower_case").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
        }

        // minimum of 1 special character in password.
        if ( a.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/) ) {
            $("#password_special_character").removeClass("password_not_recommended").addClass("password_recommended");
        } else {
            $("#password_special_character").removeClass("password_recommended").addClass("password_not_recommended");
        }

    });
```

Here is my html template code:

```
<div id="row_id_new_password1" class="form-group  ">
    <label for="id_new_password1" class="control-label  required  control-label-01">
        New password:
    </label>
    <div class="controls ">
        <input id="id_new_password1" name="new_password1" type="password" class="kmw-disabled keymanweb-font" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required." data-parsley-id="0678"><span class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-0678"></span><span class="spacer"></span><span rel="tooltip" html="true" class="no_decoration no_flicker_padding" tabindex="-1" title="" data-original-title="The longer the better. Include numbers and special characters for stronger security."><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o blue_color icon_size18"></i></span>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show sample html for 2 cases. We have no idea what the selector changes would be. Seems like overkill having so many elements when all you need is one error element and different messages

Comment: just added the 2 different sections of code.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: i am unsure how to call and pass in the changed element id to the one section of code.

Comment: the above is pretty redundant approach for password validation. It can be achieved with a single regex and one "message box"

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: but you did not show your html markup

Comment: added html code. Is this what you require?